# Minimum light bulb wattage for solar simulator

Tags: power, light, optics

I am trying to design a simple homemade solar simulator. I have picked metal-halide lamps as my light source.

To achieve an irradiance of 1000 W/m<sup>2</sup>, I don't know what wattage of light bulbs are needed.

I understand that the irradiance is going depend on a number of factors including distance of the light source from the test bed. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Are you growing pot?   Or are you doing actual scientific research of some kind.  i.e. how accurate do you need to be?

Comment: You'll need about 4,000 watts per square metre.

Comment: @KyleB This is to test a PV module.

Comment: @Andyaka I am curious how you come up with that number?

Comment: Efficiency of a Metal Halide would be around 25% (ie 75% of the power used goes to heat).  That's where the 4000 comes from.   If you don't need to light up a full square meter, you could use a smaller bulb.  This assumes of course, you're able to focus all the light on the panel.

Comment: If I intend to use multiple bulbs to cover the 1 square meter, does each bulb have to be rated for 4000W? That seems unrealistic.

Comment: TBH, even a single bulb at 4000W is unrealistic.  Most you can get from a standard outlet is 15A*120V=1800W.     Is your PV a full square meter in size????

Comment: No but I was using it as an example.

Comment: If you need to illuminate 1 sq metre at 1000 watts of light then the electrical power needed is 4 kW.

Comment: @Andyaka and others - Std Silicon PV panels are sensitive to the IR component of halogen light. I forget the figure off cuff - but could dig it up. As Halogen lights are about 100% efficient if you count the IR then you will need more than kW to simulate 1 kW of sunlight BUT not 4 x as much. I used to use halogen lamps for portable solar light testing.

Answer (score 1):

### Depends on the spectrum your solar panels care about

They don't necessarily run only on *visible* light.

In the visible range, the sun's energy is about 93 lumens per watt.  So you will need 93,000 lumens.

A 400W metal halide lamp is 36,000 lumens, but in a sphere not the cone that you want. Reflectors have loss, so I'd pencil in about 18-20,000 lumens usable.   So five 400W metal halides.

In my experience they draw about 470 VA actual, but then they need to be derated to 125% because they are lighting loads and thus deemed continuous. So you need to provision 590 VA to each light.  Five of them is not gonna happen within the 1800 VA budget you have on a single common 15A/120V circuit, nor even the 2400 VA budget you have on a 20A/120V circuit.  You'll need 2 circuits.

Don't forget to budget some energy for the *air conditioner* you're gonna need in that room lol.

Comment: I guess my real question is do I just need to make sure that 1000W of power reaches a 1m^2 surface to achieve an irradiance of 1000/m^2? Putting aside efficiency and diffusion of light, if I had 5 lamps each producing 200W laid out evenly in a 1 meter squared area, does that achieve what I need?